# OLE Web Browser rendered html page horrible(ly) but looks fine in standalone IE 11 instead

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, webbrowser-control

We're using MS-Access 2010 and referencing the OLE Web Browser control in there.

The issue we're having is when you open html file locally into standalone IE 11, it looks fine and it works.

But when you open local file in OLE Web Browser (MS-Access 2010), it rendered halfway and stopped working.  It looks horrible.

This is the code we used

```
    '[WebBrowser4].Navigate "C:\Carfax.html"
```

I'm thinking it only work with url address instead of local file, due to the way the internal OLE component works.

Suggestion?  Have anyone use other way to load webpage?

The html scripts is too long and this StackOverflow doesn't support file attachment.  So, I don't know of a way to provide html source code here.

Comment: It defaults to IE7 compat mode, see the info about doctypes and the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Registry Key here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/ - See if that fixes the issue.

Comment: We can't do registry.  It require our company support dept to call every customers to update their PC's registry.  :-(  Also, someone told me if IE 11 on workstation then this OLE Web Browser automatically use this version instead of IE 7.  So, don't know if this one is right or wrong here.  :-(

Comment: Navigate to http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ and see what the browser reports itself as being.

Comment: If you need to change the registry you can do it from VBA.

Comment: What about the *Compatibility Meta Tag* as mentioned in Alex's link?

Comment: Using "whatsmybrowser.org" url, it returned IE 11 in OLE Web Browser.  So, look like either registry hack or Compatibility Meta Tag aren't needed here.